# Entity framework update no tracking entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

How can I update an entity that is detached from context by `AsNoTracking()`?

```
var _agency = agencyRepository.Get(filter: a => a.Id == agency.Id)
                              .AsQueryable()
                              .AsNoTracking()
                              .FirstOrDefault(); 
agencyRepository.Update(_agency);
```

and my Update method already set modified:

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {            
        dbset.Attach(entity);
        dataContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Can I find the previous entity that is attached by datacontext? or any suggestion to prevent Tracking on my User entity?

Comment: What is it that you're changing and what's the actual result?

Comment: In fact I encountered the error of "Attaching an entity of type 'Project.Domain.Entities.Agency' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value", on Update() so I tried to detach the entity to solve the problem but update do nothing now.

Comment: There's no need to call `Attach` as the `Entry` method already attaches the Entity internally (if not already attached).

Comment: so why nothing's been updated?

Comment: Have you tried without calling `Attach`?

Comment: yes, I have tried. no error but no update too.

Comment: What is the change? Also, are you calling `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: Yes, I use unitOfWork.Commit(); that contains SaveChanges()

Comment: What is it that you're changing?

Comment: What happens in `agencyRepository.Get`? This `AsQueryable()` makes me suspect that something is returned that makes `AsNoTracking()` ineffective.

Comment: the result of Get() was wrong! but still I have above error on Update() even when use NoTracking.

Comment: Under the related question (now deleted) I asked for more relevant information. Without it, we can't even begin answering this question.

Answer (score 10):

you can change the state of the entity:

```
ctx.Entry(_agency).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

More Read [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) or [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) article.

Comment: This does not fix the issue for me.  I am still getting the error: "role cannot be automatically added to the context because it was retrieved using the NoTracking merge option."

Answer (score 1):

When you get your object as "AsNoTracking", it means that it's detached from the context and changes won't be tracked. All you need to do is attach it to the context again.

Here is a sample code:

```
async Task update_entity() {
  ctx.Attach(profile);
  profile.image_id = "12345667";
  await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: What if i run this code twice? If i try to attach entity that is already attached?